# Android : Setting development environment in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

Currently I just installed Ubuntu 11.10. I want setup all the tools and IDE required for android development. But here I am finding it a bit painful in ubuntu. Can anybody answer me some queries to make my job easier?

1. Everytime I open a terminal in ubuntu and try to run some program it asks me for password and I have to use the `"sudo"` word. Is there a way that I can setup a shortcut icon in the launcher where I can open the terminal and just fire up the application I want to run?
2. I recently installed the eclipse. The version is eclipse-SDK-3.7.2-linux-gtk.tar.gz. I extracted the contents. I found a file named eclipse. But I am not able to run it. I went into  the folder where the file is there. Then I tried to use the command `"./eclipse"`. Then It says permission denied. If I use `"sudo ./eclipse"`, it says command not found. Then how do I run the eclipse?

Please give some suggestions which will make my things easier in ubuntu

Comment: Well, here the problem is not Android related. You should consider the possibility to study the base concept of Linux

Comment: Please break this down into two separate questions: 1) The terminal/sudo issue and 2) the eclipse issue.  Your also going to need to learn about more about ubuntu and sudo or none of this will make sense so please study that subject.  Unfortunately I am going to vote to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be new to the Linux world..

1. most probably this happens if you don't have permission to run the program, you have to change user to root to execute. Give Execute permissions (assuming your installation is in /usr/local/bin/eclipse)

   sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/eclipse